# Weird HTML5 sliced images margin top & bottom issue

Tags: html, html4

Comparing HTML4 with HTML5, I encounter a strange problem when placing sliced images to my website.

See the example pages below:

- [HTML4 version](http://raptor.hk/dev/html5/html4.html)
- [HTML5 version](http://raptor.hk/dev/html5/html5.html)

As you can see in HTML5 version, an unwanted margin appears in image margin top & bottom, and cannot be removed via CSS overrides. How to make HTML5 version look identical to HTML4 version (in this simple case)?

p.s. the only difference of the 2 files is the header DOCTYPE declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `img {vertical-align: bottom;}` to your CSS.

Comment: bingo! but why need this fix?

Comment: Because by default the images are aligned to the text, which means they have to allow space below the line for letters such as `q`. Using `bottom` as the alignment aligns the images to the bottom of the line. The only time you'll encounter problems is if the image height is less than the height of the text (the `line-height` property).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Height & Width from Table & IMGs

Answer (score 0):

Add `img { display: block; }` to your css.  HTML5 will cause browsers to render inline stuff slightly differently to HTML4.

For more information, see this informative article from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images%2C_Tables%2C_and_Mysterious_Gaps